# iOS 5 Implementing a Page Controller with Storyboards in existing application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, uipagecontrol

I have an application that needs to display a series of graphs (using Core Plot).  I would like each of these graphs to be displayed in its own view preferably using a paged controller.  I have 8 graphs.

Can someone direct me to a resource that shows how to implement something like this in iOS 5 with storyboards?  I can't seem to find anything that explains this with storyboards at all..

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Have you checked out the Xcode project template for a Paged app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite easy. You just need to drag a UIScrollView into your controller, select it, and check the *"Paging Enabled"* option. You can also drag in a 'page control' and set yourself as the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol delegate and update it when UIScrollView calls the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Don't forget to set your UIScrollView's delegate by Control+Drag from the UIScrollView to your ViewController.

[Great tutorial on UIScrollView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) (Scroll down to "Paging with UIScrollView").

[Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html) with [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) example.

Comment: Can we do this without a scroll view? I mean only using a page control?

Comment: No. UIPageControl is just a UI element that can be used with anything and not just a ScrollView. However, only UIScrollView has the `pagingEnabled` property which gives it the paging behaviour desired. You have to programmatically update the page of the UIPageControl. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: We can do so. You can have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171613/ios-load-and-switch-between-pages-using-uipagecontol/21172351#21172351. I followed the suggestions here and was able to do so without a scroll view but by using swipe gesture recognizer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I misunderstood your question. I thought you mean if you can only use UIPageControl to have the paging functionality, that's why I said UIPageControl "can be used with anything and not just a ScrollView". There would of course be many ways to replicate paging.