# iOS - UIPageControl page indicator dots not changing with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, uiswipegesturerecognizer, current-page

I am using `UIPageControl` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to switch between 2 view controllers of my application. I have modified [this](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168) tutorial without using scroll view.

I have 2 issues:

1) Using the swipe gesture is changing the view controllers/pages but not the dots indicating the current page. I have tried

```
if (self.pageControl.currentPage == 0) {
 self.pageControl.currentPage = 1 
}
```

but I am not sure why it does not work. I have the outlet available

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

2) I am using `- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender` for changing the page. I would like to know how to change to a page on clicking on a certain dot. I mean to say that on clicking on dot 1, I should go to the first view controller and on clicking on dot 2, I should navigate to the second view controller.

Comment: any suggestion? ideas are welcome...

Comment: Is the `pageControl` outlet `nil`? Tapping on dots will be hard (they are too small, and not an easy to calculate position).

Comment: I just did like this `pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];` When I do `NSLog(@"pageControl = %@",pageControl);`, I get `pageControl = <UIPageControl: 0x8d766d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d75500>>`

Comment: I figured that out now - I was doing `pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];` That was why current page was not working. Now it works. But could you guide me as to how to change the page on clicking a particular dot - it might not be so easy but I would like to try it.

Comment: You need to know where the dots are and add buttons over them or tap gestures. I don't know how to work out where the dots are - there isn't a public API for that. And from a user point of view, the dots are too small to tap. You shouldn't do it. But feel free to add buttons / gestures to either end of the control - if they are a normal size...

Comment: Could you explain it with reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355809/ios-uibutton-on-uipagecontrol-not-working. Also, you might want to post your answer to this question.

Comment: I think - matbe you could post what you said as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know where the dots are and add buttons over them or tap gestures. I don't know how to work out where the dots are - there isn't a public API for that. And from a user point of view, the dots are too small to tap. You shouldn't do it. But feel free to add buttons / gestures to either end of the control - if they are a normal size...