# Unable to click the dots in Page Control

Tags: objective-c

Unable to click the dots in Page Control. Also, need to change the `UICollectionView` while clicking the dots. Anyone help me regarding this?

```
 -(void)changepage:(UIPageControl *)sender { 
// UIPageControl *pager=sender; 
page = sender.currentPage;
 CGRect frame = self.AchievementCollection.frame; 
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
 frame.origin.y = 0;
 [self.AchievementCollection scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]; 
NSLog(@"page control value %li",(long)sender.currentPage);
 }
```

in Cell For Item at Index Path

```
AchievementCollectionCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AchievementCollecti‌on" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
[pageControls addTarget:self action:@selector(changepage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
cell.MiddleLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"userCertificateName"]; 
cell.BottomLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"userCertificateDesc"];
 return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information and code you have written.

Comment: -(void)changepage:(UIPageControl *)sender
{
   // UIPageControl *pager=sender;
    
     page = sender.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = self.AchievementCollection.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.AchievementCollection scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"page control value %li",(long)sender.currentPage);
}

Comment: in Cell For Item at Index Path
    AchievementCollectionCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AchievementCollection" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   
    
       [pageControls addTarget:self action:@selector(changepage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    
 
   

    cell.MiddleLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"userCertificateName"];
    cell.BottomLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"userCertificateDesc"];
    return cell;
}

Comment: is it ok for u bro?

Comment: @AASHWIN  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355809/ios-uibutton-on-uipagecontrol-not-working

Comment: @AASHWIN check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779865/unable-to-click-the-dots-in-page-control

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to let the dot clickable, since it's too small for a finger gesture. If you would like something like next / back, then you better have other 2 buttons to handle that.

But, IMHO, the best UX is still let user scroll the scrollview manually.